# How to use BASH / ZSH to capture picture from webcam

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh, webcam, mdm

I am new to MDM and I am attempting to write a script/profile which will use the built in webcam (and/or external if available) to capture a photo taken from the webcam. This would only be activated if the device was reported stolen. From the research I've done so far it is sounding like this capability in not built into MacOS. We use Addigy if that is important information. Can someone:

1. Verify that this capability is or is not built into MacOS
2. If it is built into MacOS, what command do I invoke to activate this function? I'll attempt to use the "man" pages to figure the rest out form there.

Comment: Are you sure you want/need to use Bash/Zsh for this?

Comment: I'm open to other solutions if other solutions are better. The end goal is to be able to use the webcam to take a photo or a short video and upload it to a server before sending a wipe command. If better solutions exist, I'm open to hearing about those solutions. Whatever solution is implemented the current desire is to have it activated via Addigy.